# Assign function to array object that references itself using "this"

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects called `myList` inside my controller.

I'd like a clean way to check if that array of objects has an object already with a particular id.

The object structure looks like this:

```
myList: [
    {
        id: <integer>,
        .
        .
        .
    },
    ...
]
```

Assuming `var ctrl = this;` and in my onInit function within my controller:

```
function onInit() {
    $log.debug(ctrl);
    ctrl.myList.includes = function(id) {
        var found = false;
        for (var index=0; index < this.length; index++) {
            if (this[index].id === id) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Now, later on in my code elsewhere in the controller:

```
if (!ctrl.myList.includes(id) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Is this the proper way to use the `this` keyword in the `includes` function that I've assigned to `myList`?
The console isn't throwing any errors - so syntactically this is correct, but it is not working.
Maybe there's a better to go about doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype` higher order functions and write it in a chain functional way,
`function includesId(id) { return !!ctrl.myList.find(item => item.id === id); }`

Comment: Newer browsers already have an [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

Comment: @Andreas - I have a requirement to support older browser versions.

Comment: How old? `Array.prototype.some()` is also supported by IE9

Comment: @Andreas Since `Array.prototype.includes` only finds flat arrays with primitive values, it can't be used here. What's wrong with simple `Array.prototype.find`?

Comment: @Andreas - looks like `Array.prototype.some()` will work for me.  Good stuff.

Comment: @FarzadYZ You're right with `.includes()` but the main intention, that TO is overwriting a prototype method is still valid. There's nothing wrong with `.find()`. But why return an element I don't need to only convert it to a boolean instead of calling a method which will directly yield a boolean value?

Comment: @Andreas Agree. `Array.prototype.some` is the right way to go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel.
Use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```
if (!ctrl.myList.some(function(element) { return element.id === id; }) {
    // Do something...
}
```